# Generic function to update DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my display page I have a script that updates a div from another php page.

How do I re-write the below script to:
Be a function I can call with `updateadiv(divid,content)` in my display page (in php) where content is a php variable. (the script will then not call the php page but take the input variable).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>



    function updatediv(divId, content)
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#content').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#content').show();
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#content').show();
                }
            });
            var $container = $("#content");
            $container.load("http://192.168.1.90/json_output.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $container.load('http://192.168.1.90/json_output.php');
            }, 9000);
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php
    function createarray() {
global $reindexed_devices_a ;
$feed_url = "http://192.168.1.90/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=all&location1=all&location2=all";
//$feed_url = "demoxml.xml";

$json = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$devices_a = json_decode($json, true);

//echo $devices_a[Devices][2][name] ;
//echo "<BR> ReIndexed:";

$reindexed_devices_a = array(Devices => array());
foreach ($devices_a[Devices] as $value) {
    $reindexed_devices_a[Devices][$value[ref]] = $value;
}

//echo $reindexed_devices_a[Devices][59][name] ;
//need to do some conditional formatting before updating to DIV's
if ($reindexed_devices_a[Devices][59][name] == 'Coffee maker') {
 $reindexed_devices_a[Devices][59][name] = "overwritten";
}
echo time();

//echo $reindexed_devices_a[Devices][59][name] ;
}

createarray();


$name59=$reindexed_devices_a[Devices][59][name];
//check if $name59 has changed - if yes update div
updatediv('59');

    echo "This is a test <div id = 'name59'>.....</div>";
    ?>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: need to explain in more detail since php and javascript run in different environments and there is no php code shown here. Your question is currently very difficult to understand

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks, I have updated the code part of the question. Basically what Im trying to do, is to use php to design all the logic and conditional formatting, and create to functions, one that loads a JSON holding some devices and their statuses into a php array, do some formatting in php (like is value for device x<20 then make font blue), and one to update the corresponding div

Comment: still not 100% clear what specific issue is. If returning json `load()` won't help since it is for html, need to parse json to html after it is received. Also question still refers to `php variable` with no explanation

Comment: I get your point - I have tried to put the full test code in now. I load all devices in from the JSON in order to test which have changed since last load - I use php for that test. If a value from the JSON have changed, I put some formatting to it and output it to the div for the user to see. I just didnt want to upload my very messi code in order not to confuse too much. There has to be a better way than what Im going for - Im sure.

Comment: have no idea what you are talking about...  `devices` is meaningless without context. So far all you have shown is simple `load()` code

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateadiv(DivID , Url){


     $('#loading').hide();
      $('#' + DivID ).html('');

      $.ajax({
            url:url,
            success:function(rData){
           $('#' + DivID ).html(rData);
        }

        });
}
```